# Set accessory button frame

Tags: iphone, ios

In my iPhone application, I added an accessory button in each cell.

Here is my code below:

```
    ContactCell *contactCell = (ContactCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];
    if (contactCell == nil) {
        contactCell = [[ContactCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellID];
        contactCell.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, ROW_HEIGHT);
    }

    UIImage *callButtonImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"call-person.png"];
    UIButton *button =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200, ROW_HEIGHT);
    [button setBackgroundImage:callButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    ContactWrapper *cellWrapper = nil;  
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(askCallForClientContact:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            contactCell.accessoryView = button;
```

I set a button frame as: `button.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200, ROW_HEIGHT);`

But it seems that the button frame is more less than 200. When I click on a cell and suppose there is a button, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` event appear, not `askCallForClientContact:` event. How can I set frame of accessory button? I need to make it 200 width?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change the frames of accessoryView. As an alternative you can add a subview to your cell

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:aView];
```

Comment: I can add [contactCell.contentView addSubview:button];?

Comment: yes you can add a subview either its a buttob,lable,uiimage etc to your cell